# Formula Parse error when I programatically add a formula with apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, google-sheets-formula

I work in widget where the user can add datas in specific row. In the Modal Dialog, he can type the row where i want add data and select data to add.
The data is linked to an other data with a macro and i want to add too this value.

This is my server side's script :

```
function include(filename){
   return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

function widget() {
  const classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const feuille = classeur.getActiveSheet();
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var widget;
  widget = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("widget.html").evaluate();
  ui.showModalDialog(widget, "Add new Row");
  widget.setWidth(600);
  widget.setHeight(600);
}

function getData(){
  const classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const feuille = classeur.getSheetByName("BDD");
  var services = feuille.getRange("A2:A").getValues().filter(d =>d[0] !== "");
  return services.map(d => "<option>" + d[0] + "</option>").join("")
}

function ajoutLigne(row,data) {
  const classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const feuille = classeur.getActiveSheet();
  index = feuille.getActiveRange().getRow();
  feuille.insertRowBefore(row);
  feuille.getRange("A"+row).setValue(data);
  feuille.getRange("B"+row).setValue("=RECHERCHEV(A"+row+";BDD!A:B;2;FAUX)");
}
```

This is my widget's HTML page :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
     <base target="_top">
     <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
   </head>
   <body>
     <p>Row : <input type="text" id="row"></p>
     <br>
     <p><i>Select data :</i>
       <select id="data" name="data" class="form-control" required>
         <option disabled selected>Choose ...</option>
         <?!=getData()?>
       </select>
     </p>

     <input type="button" class="button" value="SUBMIT" onclick="addRow();">
     <input type="button" class="button" value="CLOSE" onclick="google.script.host.close();">

   </body>
 </html>
```

And this is my JavaScript's page :

```
<script>
   function addRow(){
     var row = document.getElementById("row").value;
     var data = document.getElementById("data").value;
     google.script.run.ajoutLigne(row,data);
   }
</script>
```

When i launch my widget and sumbit datas, it's correctly reported in my Sheet's tab. But the macro generate an error:

> formula parse error

and I don't understand why. The syntax is the same to the previous row. And if i modify 2 times the macro (first time to change one thing and second time to write the initial macro), it's work....

If anyone know the answer to this problem, I would be grateful. Thank you for advance for your help (this is [the link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ksS8AkiccbqYyaulc7S8EW4_q_h47c57C-SrZjMdWGs/edit?usp=sharing) of my Sheet).

Comment: `generate and error` What's the error? Also, use a descriptive title that summarizes the problem.

Comment: The error is "formula parse error". I edited my post

Comment: For me, because I'm in the US, `RECHERCHEV` doesn't work but `VLOOKUP` does.

Comment: RECHERCHEV is same than VLOOKUP in french. I tried with VLOOKUP but i've same error

Comment: AFAIK, Those errors are hard to debug. Usually  manually adding a space in the formula  fixes the error.

Comment: Gosh, I would have preferred to avoid this step. Thank you for your help. I l don't close this post and hope anyone can have a solution

Comment: By guessing your situation, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direct solution to your issue, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I saw your question, the formula is put using the following script.

```
feuille.getRange("B"+row).setValue("=RECHERCHEV(A"+row+";BDD!A:B;2;FAUX)");
```

But, when I saw your script included in your sample Spreadsheet, the formula is put using the following script.

```
feuille.getRange("B"+row).setValue("=VLOOKUP(A"+row+";BDD!A:B;2;FAUX)");
```

And, from your sample Spreadsheet and your comments, in the current stage, I thought that you might try to use `VLOOKUP`.

If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
feuille.getRange("B"+row).setValue("=VLOOKUP(A"+row+";BDD!A:B;2;FAUX)");
```

#### To:

```
feuille.getRange("B"+row).setFormula("=VLOOKUP(A"+row+";BDD!A:B;2;FALSE)");
```

#### Reference:

- [setFormula(formula)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula)

Comment: It's work perfectly, thank you so much. But i don't understand why it work in english language and not in french. feuille.getRange("B"+row).setValue("=RECHERCHEV(A"+row+";BDD!A:B;2;FAUX)"); is same than the last of your modification (i mistake with mine and forget to change "FAUX" to "FALSE"). But the most important thing is that it works !